# AWS folder location installed using anaconda

Tags: amazon-web-services, anaconda, aws-cli

I installed AWS CLI using Anaconda. I am using Linux Mint `19.1`. I am not sure where to find `.aws` folder because I use Anaconda instead of `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`.

Here are the paths I see using `find . -iname "aws"`:

```
./anaconda3/share/terminfo/a/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-hfc679d8_2/share/terminfo/a/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-s3/include/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-kinesis/include/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/awscli-1.16.92-py36_0/bin/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-s3/include/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-kinesis/include/aws
./anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-s3/include/aws
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-kinesis/include/aws
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/aws/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws
./anaconda3/bin/aws
```

I check these 2 paths:

```
./anaconda3/pkgs/awscli-1.16.92-py36_0/bin/aws
./anaconda3/bin/aws
```

using `find . -iname "config" | grep aws` and `find . -iname "credentials" | grep aws` but both of them don't contain `config` or `credentials` file.

So where can I find the `.aws` folder, which wasn't created? I can confirm that `aws` is installed as `aws --version` returns `aws-cli/1.16.92 Python/3.6.7 Linux/4.15.0-43-generic botocore/1.12.82`

Comment: Did you run `aws configure` after you installed it?

Comment: Good point, I will try ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was reading about the configuration and credential files here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html, I tried to find these files but was unable to.

Following @bwest suggestion, I followed the steps in the previous page here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html using the command `aws configure`, and did my `find` again.

This time I'm able to locate the `.aws` folder, `config` and `credentials` files.

So in short, if you install `awscli` the `.aws` will not be automatically created, you have to execute `aws configure`.